# Global exception page in Apache Tiles and Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

When an unhandled exception is throws (e.g. a `RuntimeException`), then I want to show a common error page.

I want to achieve a few things:

- reuse a HTML template (use a common "frame" with header etc.) and place exception info in the body
- provide some basic info about the exception in the body document

I am using Apache Tiles and Spring MVC. What is a good approach to my problem?

Part of my tiles-definitions:

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="common" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/common.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="header"/>
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp"/>
    </definition>
   ...
   <definition name="main" extends="common">
       <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/main.jsp"/>
   </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

Ideally I'd like to specify a definition for an exception page by setting the `body` attribute...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you have Spring's `TilesViewResolver` and `TilesConfigurer` configured, you can try the following bean definition:

```
<bean id="exceptionResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
   <property name="exceptionMappings">
      <props>
         <prop key="java.lang.Throwable">error</prop>
      </props>
   </property>
</bean>
```

And then simply define the logical view `error`:

```
<definition name="error" extends="common">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

This will forward any `Throwable` to the right view, where you have access to the exception itself (`${exception}`). This doesn't replace all standard HTTP error pages (for 404 etc.)

Answer (score 1):

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="common" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/common.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="header"/>
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp"/>
    </definition>
   <definition name="common11" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/common11.jsp">//common11 is same page as common.jsp
        <put-attribute name="header" value=""/>
        <put-attribute name="footer" value=""/>
    </definition>
   ...
   <definition name="main" extends="common">
       <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/main.jsp"/>
       <put-attribute name="header" value=""/>
        <put-attribute name="footer" value=""/>
   </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using struts 2.0 then in struts.xml, 
You can use as following,
Or if you are using jsp servlet then you can use following in web.xml

```
<global-results>
<result name="error">/WEB-INF/jsp/common.jsp</result>
</global-results>
```